# How To Create A Grid Of Images That Scale

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a grid of images that scale as the page resizes. In my implementation, I have the images scaling but they are not lining up in a grid. When there are assets of different sizes on the same row, the smaller asset's height is always shorter than the other assets. How would I get it so that the images maintain their aspect ratio when scaling, and their heights are all the same?

https://jsfiddle.net/x2wqup0e/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tile col-1">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-5">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-2">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-4">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/600x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/600x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-2">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-2">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-2">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x250">
  </div>
</div>



.col-1 {
  width: 16.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 33.3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 50.0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 66.6%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 83.3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tile {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Edit #1 - I have removed the padding between each tile so now the tiles are scaling correctly while maintaining their aspect ratio and height. I however have lost the spacing between each tile which creates the grid effect: https://jsfiddle.net/dcgf2coq/1/

Comment: since the assets have different width the height will always change as soon as the width varies (since we need to maintain aspect ratio)

Comment: @RRR Is there anyway to make it so that the heights of each `.tile` stay consistent even if the aspect ratios are slightly different?

Comment: aspect ratio will go for a toss... you can try setting `.thumb {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}`  not sure its right to do that

Comment: @Jon You can set the images as the background image of a tile and crop them with CSS. 

It makes sense that this only happens when one of the images is smaller, because in the case of images with equal width/height the aspect ratio of all three images is the same, so they will resize exactly the same.

Comment: @Jon add `display:flex` to `.tile`

`.tile {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  display:flex;
}`

Comment: kindly check updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x2wqup0e/2/

Comment: @RRR - I took a look at your Fiddle, but the images are being stretched too much. I have updated my post with new findings where I have removed padding from `.tile`.

Comment: @reinder - I have updated my post with a new Fiddle where I have removed padding from `.tile`. The issue I am facing now is how I would create a border effect around each `.tile`

Comment: Try to put an outline directly on the image

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, i think this is your need?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/600x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/600x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x250">
  </div>
  <div class="tile col-3">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.tile {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```